# Mobx method's object is not a function

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to access a method's objet (here `greet()` method) throught a mobx array, but I'm stuck with :

> TypeError: person.greet is not a function

**Person class**

I have a Person class, with `greet` method :

```
export class Person {
    public id: number = Date.now();
    public firstName!: string;
    public lastName!: string;

    public greet() : string {
        return "Hello!";
    }
};
```

**Store**

My store look like :

```
import { persist } from "mobx-persist";
import { observable, computed, action } from "mobx";
import { Person } from "../models/Person";

export class PersonStore {

    @persist('list')
    @observable
    personList: Person[] = [];

    @computed get entries(): Person[] {
        return this.personList.slice();
    };
};
```

**In the component**

In my component, I pass the list like that :

```
const PeoplePage_: React.FunctionComponent<{ personStore: PersonStore }> = ({ personStore }) => {

    return (
        <PeoplePage
            personList={personStore.entries} />
    );
};
export default inject("personStore")(observer(PeoplePage_));
```

And then in my `PeoplePage`component, when I'm doing something like :

```
personList[0].greet()
```

I'm getting the error.

Comment: mmmmh, I think that's coming from "mobx-persist" lib. `@persist('list')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the lib `mobx-persist` and then the line `@persist('list')`

This mean that my array is stored and the retrieved in plain object style (`{firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'foo'}`).

The trick is to construct a new `Person` in the component.

I added a constructor with an objet to repopulate.

```
export class Person {
    public id: number = Date.now();
    public firstName!: string;
    public lastName!: string;

    constructor(private obj: any = null) {
        if(obj){Object.assign(this, obj)}
    }

    public greet(): string {
        return `Hello, ${this.firstName}`;
    }
};
```

Then in my component:

`new Person(person).greet()`